# Microsoft Ege and localtion folder?

Tags: windows, dreamweaver

in what folder is located Microsoft Edge broswer? I can't find it. Just wanted add it to default browser of dreamweaver.

Answer (score -1):

**Go to My PC Local Disc C > Windows > System Apps there you will see some windows apps folders ..one of them is Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge .
Its simple :)**

Comment: I have found here: C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe but try to launch the application it not start.

Comment: you mean that you tried to launch from Dream Weaver or  simply by clicking launcher icon of Edge ??